# AChartEngine Time Chart with multiple Y scales and axis

Tags: achartengine

How can I create a Time Chart with multiple Y scales and axis with AChartEngine? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to build a `CombinedXYChart` of line charts and use custom labels instead of the default ones.

`TimeChart` is not supported in the `CombinedXYChart`.

**Update**: See [this](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/demo/org/achartengine/chartdemo/demo/chart/MultipleTemperatureChart.java) example and just create a time chart instead of a cubic line chart.

Comment: I don't want to use a CombinedXYChart since I want to present the same type of chart (line charts).
What I want to do is something like the example "MultipleTemperatureChart" where CubicLineChart is used with 2 Y axis. My question is if it's possible to use a TimeChart similarly to the example? Thanks

Comment: I can't do that because when I create a XYSeries as in the example I give different scale number (0 and 1 to each chart line)
XYSeries series = new XYSeries(titles[i], 0);
XYSeries series = new XYSeries(titles[i], 1);
...but the TimeSeries constructor doesn't allow this argument, right? What can I do?