# AChartEngine multiple axis scales

Tags: achartengine

I want to show both metric and English scales on my charts like this example. How can it be done?

Image:
[image]

Comment: Is this related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623752/achartengine-time-chart-with-multiple-y-scales-and-axis?rq=1

Comment: related but different. I have searched for this answer. Thanks, rene, for adding my image to my post.

Comment: Can you add the code you already tried?

Comment: I haven't found a way to even try this. I made the image from a chart that just had scales on the bottom and the left, using Photoshop.

Comment: Spent the next 15 minutes [reading this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the pages it links to. Your question now is more like a 'give me the code' question and those tend to be closed and/or downvoted...

Comment: I don't need any code, just the method. I read the page about how to post a good question already. The related answer you mentioned earlier is about plotting two series with different scales. But I need to plot one series that has two different scales, metric and English. Related, but different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AChartEngine supports multiple Y axis, but not multiple X axis and no X axis on the top of the chart. You will have to add an extension of AChartEngine for that and maybe contribute it back to the project.

Comment: Thank you, Dan. I will implement that extension. I'm really enjoying incorporating AChartEngine in our apps, by the way.